# How to search for an object between desired pixels?

Tags: c++, opencv, viola-jones

As I mentioned in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431348/do-i-have-to-train-viola-jones-algorithm-with-my-database-to-obtain-accurate-res) I can't get accurate results about detecting facial features with Viola - Jones algorithm. Especially while obtaining eyes singly and mouth, it does not work well. But there's no problem about detecting face, eyes pair and nose. So that I thought of a **simple algorithm** which is:

- Step 1: Detect face
- Step 2: Detect eyes pair
- Step 3: Search for a nose below eyes pair
- Step 4: Search for a mouth below nose
- Step 5: Find the middle point of eyes pair. Search for a left eye on
  the right hand side of midpoint and above nose.
- Step 6: Do the same thing for right eye.

While detecting objects I use **cvHaarDetectObjects** method. But with this method it looks like it is not possible to search for an object between desired pixels. So is there some function like "**Get this image, and search for a nose between x and y, and x + width and y + height pixels and give me the coordinates of nose.**"

Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It is not necessary to search between desired pixels. Viola - Jones Algorithm already finds the features in the way like the **simple algorithm** above. So if you search for the objects sequentially it finds facial features without any problem. Here is an example code:

```
    void Detection::Detect()
{
    FacialFeatures* facialFeatures = new FacialFeatures();

    DrawRectangle(DetectFeature(faceDetector));
    DrawRectangle(DetectFeature(eyesDetector));
    DrawRectangle(DetectFeature(noseDetector));
    DrawRectangle(DetectFeature(mouthDetector));
    DrawRectangle(DetectFeature(leftEyeDetector));
    DrawRectangle(DetectFeature(righteyeDetector));
}

CvRect* Detection::DetectFeature(const char* detectorType)
{
    pCascade_ = (CvHaarClassifierCascade* ) cvLoad(detectorType,0,0,0);
    pRectSeq_ = cvHaarDetectObjects(pImage_, pCascade_, pStorage_, 1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(20,20));
    CvRect* r = (CvRect*) cvGetSeqElem(pRectSeq_,0);
    return r;
}

void Detection::DrawRectangle(CvRect* r)
{
    cvNamedWindow("Detected", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    CvPoint pt1 = { r->x, r->y };
    CvPoint pt2 = { r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height };
    cvRectangle(pImage_, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 3, 4, 0);

    cvShowImage("Detected", pImage_);
    cvWaitKey(0);
}
```